# Android can not remove \n from String

Tags: android, string, replace, textview

I have a String I have to display in a TextView with Html.fromHtml(), but it contains sometimes a few \n at the end of the text, so TextView shows empty lines.
I tried to remove \n by

```
    text = text.replace('\n', ' ');
    text = text.replace("\n", "");
    text = text.replace("\\n", "");
    text = text.replaceAll("\\n", "");
    text = text.replaceAll("\\\\n", "");
```

than I insert the text into TextView like this

```
tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(text, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY, null, new CustomTagHandler(context, cp)));
```

But non of these removed the \n from the end of the text. When I check my layout at Layout inspector I can see the TextView's content, and the \n at the end of the text.

Comment: One of them should work. If it is at the end `text = text.trim();` would do too.

Comment: Just use `tv.setText(text);`. Now what do you see?

Comment: Trim is suppose to work. as @greenapps said.

Comment: Thanks. If I tried to trim the text, but I can still see the empty lines, and I can see two \n-s at the end of the text at layout inspector.
Set text by setText() instead of setText(Html.fromHtml()) works, I mean I can't see \n-s, but I have to set text with Html.fromHtml(), so it isn't a solution in my case.